# Linq to SQL filter query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, filter

I have a database in which there are 3 columns. First is the a machine name column, followed by a state column and finally a datetime column reg_Data. This is a database which tracks production machines and its state is registered every minute or so resulting in multiple entries for each machine. I need to display only entries with a specific state. Further to this i need to only display one entry per machine, but if the current state of the machine is equal to maintenance, and then i need to show the oldest entry. If there is a newer state of the machine i need this to replace the entry but still show the oldest entry of that specific state.

Can this be achieved with a linq statement?

Comment: The answer to your question is YES. You should first try it and then come back and ask for help if you can't figure out how to implement everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, yes since linq can handle multiple statements.